# Lint api and kotlin api is too old,which may cause java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion

Tags: android, sdk

when i write custom lint rule with kotlin like this:

```
class AlarmDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {
companion object Issues {
    private val IMPLEMENTATION = Implementation(
        AlarmDetector::class.java,
        Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE
    )

    /** Alarm set too soon/frequently   */
    @JvmField
    val ISSUE = Issue.create(
        id = "ShortAlarm",
        briefDescription = "Short or Frequent Alarm",
        explanation = """
        Frequent alarms are bad for battery life. As of API 22, the `AlarmManager` will override \
        near-future and high-frequency alarm requests, delaying the alarm at least 5 seconds into the \
        future and ensuring that the repeat interval is at least 60 seconds.

        If you really need to do work sooner than 5 seconds, post a delayed message or runnable to a \
        Handler.""",
        category = Category.CORRECTNESS,
        priority = 6,
        severity = Severity.WARNING,
        implementation = IMPLEMENTATION
    )
}
other code ...
```

after assemble lint.jar and place it to "/.android/lint"

it run fine in my project with android gradle plugin:3.1.1

but when i use the lint tools in android sdk (sdk/tools/bin/lint) with command: lint --show

I got error

```
Could not load custom lint check jar file 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
```

i found the latest sdk tools is 26.1.1 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools

which the version of lint&lint-api&lint-check is 26.0.0-dev
the version of kotlin-stdlib is 1.1.3 
it's too old
I hope the lint in SDK tools can update

Comment: 我大概知道了，Android gradle Plugin 3.1之后  SDK Tools 里面的功能都可以通过gradle插件实现了，所以大概是SDK Tools 没有更新的必要了

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?